# How to initialize char * in c++ class? (sizeof() always gives 8)

Tags: c++, file, pointers, memory

I'm facing some troubles with code for my school. The problem is that I have a char pointer named "contenido" like this:

```
class Archivo {
 public:
  Archivo(const char *filename, int banderas);
  Archivo(const char *filename, int banderas, mode_t modo);
  ~Archivo();
  size_t lee(size_t nbytes);
  size_t escribe(const void *buffer, size_t nbytes);
  char *get_contenido();
  void cerrar();

 protected:
  string nombreArchivo;
  int fd;

  //Problematic char pointer
  char *contenido;
};
```

The code is supposed to be a class implementation of the c functions `read()`, `write()` and `open()`, the specific method where i need to set a new size for my char pointer is `size_t lee(size_t nbytes);` that i implemented like this:

```
size_t Archivo::lee(size_t nbytes) {
  contenido = new char[nbytes];
  cout << "contenido: " << sizeof(contenido) << endl;
  nbytes = read(fd, contenido, sizeof(contenido));
  return nbytes;
}
```

In this method, I should receive a new size for "contenido" that in this case, it works as my buffer for the read() function but unfortunately, it doesn't matter which value I use it always returns "8" in the call of `sizeof(contenido)`. I have tried using `malloc()` in the constructor, using `malloc()` and then `realloc()` and as you may see using `new char[size_t]` but in every single case I receive the same result of "8". I researched about this and in most cases the suggestion was to use std::vector but in this specific case it's necessary to use char * due to the request of my professor. I hope you can help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: You say C++ in your title, so please remove C tag.

Comment: Sizeof is doing what it should: returning the pointer size, not the data size. For the data size, you have your own variable `nbytes`.

Comment: `contenido` is a pointer and `sizeof(contenido)` will always give pointers size.

Comment: `sizeof` of a pointer is always 8 bytes on a 64-bit platform. It does not matter what you initialize it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `sizeof()` operator on a pointer, therefore you get the size of the pointer and not the size of content it's pointing to. Pointer in memory is usually like another regular variable (int for example) except it contains an address instead of an actual value. You always get the number 8 probably because your machine is 64 bit, so a pointer should be able to hold any address in the 64 bit space. (8 bytes = 64 bit)

If you want to get the size in bytes of the content (the memory you allocated), you should take the size of char (the type the content is made of) using `sizeof()` and then multiply that by the number of chars allocated, like so:

`sizeof(char)*nbytes`

Comment: My bad, i did not realize that it was giving me the value of the pointer and not of the full space of memory, now is working as intended and it's clearer to me the results, thanks to everyone!

Comment: @UnTraDe: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, per definition (even if that 1 does not mean 8 bit, it's still 1). The multiplication is not necessary.

Comment: @deviantfan It was more intended to explain the difference between the size of the type allocated and the pointer itself

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(contenido)` evaluates to the size of a pointer, which is 8 on your platform.

To restore the contents of a string, you need to use the length of the string as argument to `read`.

```
size_t Archivo::lee(size_t nbytes) {
  contenido = new char[nbytes];
  cout << "contenido: " << sizeof(contenido) << endl;
  nbytes = read(fd, contenido, nbytes);
  return nbytes;
}
```

If `contenido` is supposed to be a null terminated string, you probably need to allocate one more byte for it and make sure to add the terminating null character.

```
size_t Archivo::lee(size_t nbytes) {
  contenido = new char[nbytes+1];
  cout << "contenido: " << sizeof(contenido) << endl;
  nbytes = read(fd, contenido, nbytpes);
  contenido[nbytes] = '\0';
  return nbytes;
}
```